# Sending messages to the real mobile phone numbers

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, message, phone-number

Right now I am working in this project, so I made a project like this, when the bank worker upload the file with xlsx extension to our bank's site, all the values (phone number, message) in the excel file are placed in the database. When the values are uploaded to the database, the column named status takes the value 0 by default. Then I get all values with status 0 from the database. I want to send the messages,which belongs to their phone numbers in the database to their real mobile phones. What exactly can I do with the last part I said? I would appreciate it if you could suggest explanations or links about it. Is there any free program I can use here?

Comment: you can buy a server to do that, or you can pay someone else's server to do so

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no way to do it for free, right? @Stultuske

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send the message via SMS Gateway, which is a service that enables you to send SMS.

The SMS Gateway should be provided by the bank (assuming the bank is your client), as SMS Gateway is a paid service, based on how many characters sent, and how many SMS sent, there are charges and cost.

How it works is the same as calling a normal API. You'll need to get the API Specification from the client.